# added button to uitableviewcell not responding

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a custom tableviewcell through interface builder with a label and a button. In the .h and .m file I have made outlets and actions for the button which I have connected.
This cell is added to a tableview controlled by a uiviewcontroller class. However my problem is that when I tap the button, the button is not activated, however I am pushed on to the detailed view belonging to the cell. It seems like the button is behind the cell.

Any suggestions for what I have forgotten or should change?

I have created a button programatically and added as subview to the cell instead and this works, however this gives me another problem as the button is added everytime a cell is loaded.

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 100.0f, 40.0f)];


//Set image
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPackage.png"];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[img release];


[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myPackagePushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:button];
```

I would really like to use the interface builder approach - any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

also

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPackage.png"]; here you are not allocating memory so no need for

[img release]; because there is a possibility of crash

Answer (score 1):

The button should fire the IBAction method that you have set in IB. Have you checked by inserting an NSLog or by setting a breakpoint if the method is entered?

Is the button set to be initially activated in IB?

The crux with the IB construction is that the IBOutlet gets its value when the cell is loaded from the xib. The IBOutlet will then be the button in the cell that the tableview happend to load last.

WHen you add the button programatically, you might need to have the previous added button to removeFromSuperview before you add a button again to that cell.

Comment: Okay so it might only be in the last cell the button is actually working when created with interface builder. I followed the approach with removing the buttons from superview before adding again and it works. It just bugs me that the approach with IB is so difficult.

Comment: Actually, In both IB and programatically added button you have to consider how to detect which tableviewcell the pressed sits in. One way can be to have a dictionary with the button objects as keys and information about the cell as value. In the IBAction action:(id)sender the dictionary is asked for value with the key equal to the sender parameter of the action method.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the button was a subview of the background view.

Buttons assigned to the background view apparently can't respond to touches.